# R assign same value for all rows in column A if values are the same in columns B and C using loop

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

see below part of my original dataset.

What i want to do is to compare the rows.
for all the rows that have the same value in "tezgnr150" AND in "KLASSE", i want to assign them the same value for "q347_ref". Thereby it should not take the zero value, but the bigger number. important: i do not want to change any of the other column values (e.g. "GWLNR", "H1").

Example: as row 4 to 8 in my dataset all have "tezgnr150" = 120009 and "KLASSE" = 10, i want them all to get the same values for "q347_ref", by changing the ones which now are zero, to 98.4, as this is the value the other rows with the same tezgnr150 & KLASSE already have.

Can somebody help me finding a good loop or code in general for that?
Thank you very much in advance!

```
 FID   tezgnr150 KLASSE NAMN       GWLNR        H1    H2       q347_ref
   
6322    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
6848    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
7885    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
4564    120009     10 Peute Goutte N_A          37193 37194     98.4
4737    120009     10 Le Dorfbach  N_A          37195 37196      0  
6849    120009     10 Peute Goutte CH0057310000 37193 37194     98.4
7889    120009     10 Le Dorfbach  CH0031350000 37195 37196      0  
686     120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34545 34678      0  
2247    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34207 34682    819. 
3302    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34646 34671      0    
3847    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34663 34668       0 
4368    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34548 34677       0 
4700    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34654 34669       0 
4903    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34653 34670       0 
5978    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34627 34672       0 
8587    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34207 34682     819.
8597    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34614 34675       0  
10163   120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34664 34665       0 
10657   120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34664 34665       0 
367     120026      4 Rhein        CH0000010000 33490 37093     363.  
2991    120026      4 Rhein        CH0000010000 33520 33521       0 
2998    120026      4 Rhein        CH0000010009 33513 33518       0 
5127    120026      4 Rhein        CH0000010009 33513 33518       0 
7224    120026      4 Rhein        CH0000010000 33512 37090       0 
8811    120026      4 Rhein        CH0000010000 33490 37093     363.
10837   120026      4 Rhein        CH0000010000 33493 37092       0 
909     120026      9 Mulinbach    CH0033010000 33496 37091       0 
6182    120026      9 N_P          CH0033030000 33500 33509       0 
9321    120026      9 Mulinbach    CH0033010000 33506 33507       0 
908     120026     10 N_P          CH0033000000 33490 37093     363.
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the first 5 or 10 rows from your own data and also show the expected output? It sounds a bit vague for now.

Comment: Or you please provided an expected output in this given example

Comment: of course. so if row 1 and 2 would supposedly both have sepal.length = 4.8 and both would have sepal.width = 3.5, and let's say row 1 has petal.length = 1.5 and row 2 has petal.length = NA, then i want row 2 to take the same value in petal.length as row 1, so 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (as asked in comments)

```
df %>% group_by(tezgnr150, KLASSE) %>% mutate(across(starts_with('q347'), ~max(.))
```

**update**

```
df %>% group_by(tezgnr150, KLASSE) %>% mutate(q347_ref = max(q347_ref))
# A tibble: 30 x 8
# Groups:   tezgnr150, KLASSE [6]
     FID tezgnr150 KLASSE NAMN         GWLNR           H1    H2 q347_ref
   <int>     <int>  <int> <chr>        <chr>        <int> <int>    <dbl>
 1  6322    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 2  6848    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 3  7885    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 4  4564    120009     10 Peute Goutte N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 5  4737    120009     10 Le Dorfbach  N_A          37195 37196     98.4
 6  6849    120009     10 Peute Goutte CH0057310000 37193 37194     98.4
 7  7889    120009     10 Le Dorfbach  CH0031350000 37195 37196     98.4
 8   686    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34545 34678    819  
 9  2247    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34207 34682    819  
10  3302    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34646 34671    819
# ... with 20 more rows
```

By any chance, if there are negative values, you may also do this

```
df %>% group_by(tezgnr150, KLASSE) %>% mutate(q347_ref = mean(q347_ref[q347_ref != 0]))

# A tibble: 30 x 8
# Groups:   tezgnr150, KLASSE [6]
     FID tezgnr150 KLASSE NAMN         GWLNR           H1    H2 q347_ref
   <int>     <int>  <int> <chr>        <chr>        <int> <int>    <dbl>
 1  6322    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 2  6848    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 3  7885    120009      6 La Largue    N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 4  4564    120009     10 Peute Goutte N_A          37193 37194     98.4
 5  4737    120009     10 Le Dorfbach  N_A          37195 37196     98.4
 6  6849    120009     10 Peute Goutte CH0057310000 37193 37194     98.4
 7  7889    120009     10 Le Dorfbach  CH0031350000 37195 37196     98.4
 8   686    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34545 34678    819  
 9  2247    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34207 34682    819  
10  3302    120021      5 Albula       CH0002820000 34646 34671    819  
# ... with 20 more rows
```

---

Earlier answer

I think you want something like this

```
df <- read.table(text = "col1 col2 col3
1.5   0.2  1.3   
1.5   0.2  NA
1.4   0.3  1.6
1.7   0.3  1.7
1.6   1.2  NA
1.6   1.2  3.2", header = T)

df

  col1 col2 col3
1  1.5  0.2  1.3
2  1.5  0.2   NA
3  1.4  0.3  1.6
4  1.7  0.3  1.7
5  1.6  1.2   NA
6  1.6  1.2  3.2

library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  mutate(col3 = mean(col3, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   col1, col2 [4]
   col1  col2  col3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   1.5   0.2   1.3
2   1.5   0.2   1.3
3   1.4   0.3   1.6
4   1.7   0.3   1.7
5   1.6   1.2   3.2
6   1.6   1.2   3.2
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. i still got NA's where i wanted values.

Comment: sorry, i now updated my question, hope it's more clear now!

Comment: I want to replace the zeros. in the dataset there should not be more than one value per tezgnr150 & KLASSE pair, such that either it's the value or zero. not sure if it would be best to change them into NA's first?

Comment: yeeess it worked, thank you so much!!! :) one last question, if i want to do it with more columns than just q347_ref, but in the exact same way... how could i loop over these columns?

Comment: okay, so this would be right? : df %>% group_by(tezgnr150, KLASSE) %>% mutate(across(c(q347_ref, q347_2035, q347_2060, q347_2095), max))

Comment: q347_2035, q347_2060 and q347_2095 as i wrote in the code